# Method to make one of two data arrays less detailed / reduce total length?

Tags: javascript, object, dataset, standard-deviation

I have two x-y datasets that form two potentially related scatter plots.

The first dataset has an approximate domain (x-axis) of 0 to 25,000 and range (y-axis) of 0 to 0.3. The second dataset has an approximate domain of 0 to 550 and range of 0 to 4.5. The first dataset is much more precise and can be considered correct.

The the x and y axis for each dataset is stored in the form of (example)  `data: { xAxis: [0,1,2,3,4...], yAxis: [0.20779456198215485, 0.20824825763702393, 0.20915564894676208, 0.20960935950279236...] }`.

**How would I properly remove or reduce x-y coordinate pairs in the first dataset object to have the same amount of points in the second object (so that they may be overlaid for use in graphing / standard deviation)?**

I don't necessarily need code, I'm just asking for help on how to approach the problem in a way that maintains some integrity of the data and doesn't just remove data randomly. I suppose one method could be to return spearman's correlation constant for the result of removing various points from the dataset and assign the final result to whatever dataset point removal returns the highest spearman constant.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You could do a quadruple assignment to the lowest length using `Math.min` and then combine the remaining data:

```
xAxis.length = yAxis.length = xAxis2.length = yAxis2.length = Math.min(xAxis.length, xAxis2.length);
return { xAxis, yAxis, xAxis2, yAxis2 }
```

```js
let 
dataset_1 = { xAxis: [0,1,2], yAxis: [0,1,2] },
dataset_2 = { xAxis: [0,1,2,3,4], yAxis: [0,1,2,3,4] }

function combine(d1,d2) {
let {xAxis, yAxis} = d1, 
{xAxis: xAxis2, yAxis: yAxis2} = d2;

xAxis.length = yAxis.length = xAxis2.length = yAxis2.length = Math.min(xAxis.length, xAxis2.length);

return { xAxis, yAxis, xAxis2, yAxis2 }
}

console.log( 
  combine(dataset_1, dataset_2) 
);
```

---

### Caveat:

The above will only work if your grouping of `x` and `y` information is in sync and both arrays are the same length. Most would assume this is the case, but feel free to comment if not.

Comment: I meant to state that there is a data point for each integer in the range for each dataset. So the first dataset has an x-axis with 25,000 values and the second dataset has an x-axis with 550 values, making the length of the two datasets different. Unless of course you mean if the x and y arrays for each independent dataset are equal within the scope of a single dataset, in which case they are.

Comment: @About7Deaths So the data is relational and not separate ?

Comment: Imagine the first data set is recorded at low resolution during stage 3/10 for a process while the second data set is recorded at high resolution during stage 10/10 for the same product. So the data comes from the same source, but isn't necessarily related in the same ways, however it is possible that there is a direct correlation.